# Maven: getting jar file with merged name

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, dependencies

In my web application, I got 2 jars whose name is merged with group id, artifact id and version as below.

org.springframework.security-spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar

org.springframework-spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar

I tried to find it using dependency:tree, but could not find why it is happening.
How to resolve this, how can I find how this jar coming to my target\web-x.x.x\WEB-INF\lib folder.

Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T13:28:13+05:30)
Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Include your pom.xml and output of `dependency:tree`

Comment: My pom and dependecy:tree is too long to be added here, but if I remove below dependency from my pom, those 2 jars are not getting created with merged file name.

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>